# MySQL InnoDB transaction rollback is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii, transactions

I had a problem with a transaction sent from Yii framework (using PDO) to InnoDB MySql database, the problem was: rollback was not working, update statement was committing right away.

- I tried setting autoCommit explicitly, with no luck.
- Checked Mysql general log, only one Connection is being open, with one Start transaction sent, and later only one rollback.
- In the general log, "Start transaction", "rollback" and the update statement were all from the same client thread.
- No commit was found in the whole log.
- Tried a rollback example from a mysql client (MySQLWorkbench) and rollback worked!

The problem was just that MySql was committing right away when its sent from the Yii app and I didn't know why.

For no particular reason, I just tried enabling log_bin in my.cnf and the rollback worked!!

Can someone please explain what just happened?

I'm using MySql 5.6.25, with PHP 5.6.10 and Yii 1.1.14.

**Update:**

Turns out that I have made a mistake, I thought the rollback worked after enabling log_bin, but it didn't.

So now I'm back to the original problem, the rollback is not working, and here is the source code:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try {

    $data = array();
    // fill some data here..
    $model = Model::createOrUpdate($data);

    $errors = $model->getErrors();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors []= $e->getMessage();
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $msg = 'Success message!';
    $transaction->commit();
    echo CJSON::encode(array('success', $msg));
} else {
    if ($transaction->active) {
        $transaction->rollback();
    }
    echo CJSON::encode(array('error', implode(', ', $errors)));
}

Yii::app()->end();
```

Comment: What queries did you execute? MySQL does not know DDL-Level-Transactions.

Comment: No DDL were executed, it was just an Update statement

Comment: show your code  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I found the reason behind that.
Basically the method:

```
Model::createOrUpdate($data);
```

is calling a stored procedure within, so if anyone is having this issue, please check if that's covered.